# Rails Deployment 101

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, heroku, capistrano

I am about to deploy my 1st Rails app. I am stuck as I don't know what exactly I need to do. I   know about Heroku, AWS, Capistrano and the like, but don't know exactly what they do, and what their benefits are.

I kinda know some things, but all are blurry and ambiguous since I have no formal training and learn as I go. So basically I need someone to explain the general anatomy of Rails deployment.

Something like: 'To make any app working on the web you need the following components... Ways to make this component work with Rails are following. Alternatives are these. These are pros and cons.' Not into too much detail, but general and comprehensive 101 guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you may be confused is that there are a number of ways to do it. :D

Heroku provides one of the easiest solutions for basic deployments.  You don't need capistrano, just git. (they provide a toolset to assist).  Just git push heroku master. Also nice is that a simple deployment on heroku is free;  you can pay for more power when you actually need it.

But if you need a little extra functionality that heroku can't provide, you have to host elsewhere, such as a private virtual host.

Capistrano is a set of recipes that help build a deployment environment, sort of like rake tasks.  It does so in a very organized manner and allows for easy rollbacks.  You define the hosts, their roles, and then the recipes use ssh and scp to set up the evironment. (the server also has to be ready to accept rails applications, through something like passenger)

Comment: thanks! I have a minimal budget and would like some more control and knowledge about deploying and how it all functions... So I guess Heroku is off for me... So a basic outline would be, find a old pc, make it a unix server and host on that machine using Capistrano?

Comment: Heroku is free for little traffic, and it won't charge you without your permission; it's actually very good for easy, initial deployment.  Keep in mind, both of these options are for hosting where others can reach it;  heroku takes care of all the server management, whereas doing your own server and capistrano, you also have to learn the whole system administration gig.   For development you don't need either; just develop locally.   If you want to learn the nuts and bolts of hosting, then sure, make a linux box with nginx or apache + passenger, and then use capistrano to deploy.

Comment: I'd second Heroku. Default go to hosting.

Answer (score 2):

The Rails and Ruby World(s) are pretty noisy, so I understand your confusion.

At the end of the day, you need your rails **app** on a **server**.

Now, even the term *server* can be a little confusing, because it is generally associated with

1. A remote machine
2. A program handling HTTP requests.
   (for example **webrick or thin** which you start when you are developing on your computer and type **rails s**)

In your case you actually want a remote computer (hooked up to the net) which is running a program called a server to process HTTP requests and forward these to your app which in turn produces a request...

**Heroku** will help you out with that. (However Heroku adds several layers of abstraction to the mix. So it is not like you have one computer sitting somewhere in the heroku office, serving your application.) Heroku is dead simple to setup with git and rails.
And in the end all that is need to get your app to the "remote server" is a simple **git push.**

Read the beginner articles on https://devcenter.heroku.com/

I would also suggest for now: Forget about **Capistrano**.

Oh and you can think of **AWS (or probably S3)** as some sort of external hard drive, which your app can use to store larger pieces of data (like images, videos etc.)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the server part :) I also commented on that other guy above, so check that and would love to get your feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a deployment guide with a good shell script which support Nginx + RVM + Unicorn: [deploy_rails](https://github.com/tangramor/deploy_rails)

Comment: what about "Heroku, AWS, Capistrano"?